# JSON object not converting into javascript correctly , JSON sent as a call back from php to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've been looking for days and reading close questions and answers trying to solve this issue but not much luck ...

I've used `json_encode($Final_info);` to make a JSON object out of a php array as a return to an AJAX function like so

```
     <?php .
    .
    .
    $json = json_encode($Final_info);
                    echo $json;
... ?>
```

and the AJAX function is like so

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : ajaxurl,
         data :sent_array , 
         success :
         function(Final_info){
**var Final_info = JSON.parse( Final_info );**
//rest of code
}
```

when I try to parse the JSON object to use the contents of the array in javascript it shows me this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I also would like to note that in the php code I can print the array just fine and also when I alert the JSON object in the JSON format it doesnt show errors

```
in php 
Array
(
    [prov_fname] => someone
    [prov_lname] => someone
    [prov_email] => someone@gmail.com
    [prov_gender] => female
    [prov_age] => 2
    [prov_phone] => 700000
)

JSON :     {"prov_fname":"someone","prov_lname":"someone","prov_email":"someone@gmail.com","prov_gender":"female","prov_age":"2","prov_phone":"700000"}
```

Comment: log (client side) what you receive.  You may be receiving some php Notice in html before the json because of some warnings in the code not shown prior to echoing the json (server side).

Comment: The only thing that appears when I log the results is the contents of the JSON object shown above...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the answer was to simply add `async:false` to the ajax call, hope this helps someone out!